# Why do I get undefined reference to TextOut() function in Windows API?

Tags: c++, winapi

Here is all my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WNDProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMSG, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow) {

  WNDCLASSEX wincls;
  HWND first;
  UINT last;

  wincls.lpfnWndProc = WNDProc;
  wincls.hInstance = hInstance;
  wincls.lpszClassName = _T("ISSA_CLASS");
  wincls.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1); 

  if (!RegisterClassEx(&wincls)) {
    MessageBox(first, _T("Register failed"), _T("Yeah baby"), last);
    return 1;
} 

  TCHAR szwincls[] = _T("win32app");
  TCHAR title[] = _T("Neptune's Limit");

  HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(szwincls, title, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 200, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL); 

  if (!hwnd) {
    MessageBox(first, _T("Register failed"), _T("Yeah baby"), last);
    return 1;
}

  ShowWindow(hwnd, ncmdshow);
  UpdateWindow(hwnd);

  MSG message;

  while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0)) {

    TranslateMessage(&message);
    DispatchMessage(&message);

}

  return (int) message.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WNDProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMSG, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)  
{  
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;  
    HDC hdc;  
    TCHAR greeting[] = _T("Hello, World!");  

        switch(uMSG) {

        case WM_PAINT:    
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);  

        TextOut(hdc, 5, 5, greeting, _tcslen(greeting));   

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);  
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY: 
        PostQuitMessage(0);  
        break;  

    default:  
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMSG, wParam, lParam);  
        break;   
}

    return 0;  
}
```

At runtime in the command prompt, this produces an 'undefined reference to TextOut@20'. I know that there has been a similar question asked, and I did read the answer, but I don't see why I should have to link the gdi library. This code is almost directly out of MSDN, and they use TextOut() and it works like a charm. Also, I'm trying to use as little outside sources as possible for this project. I'm actually coding this in Windows Notepad and compiling it into an executable in the command prompt. Why shouldn't TextOut() work in this code? It looks like the syntax is correct, but what should I know? I'm just learning this stuff.

Comment: *but I don't see why I should have to link the gdi library.* - because `_TextOut@20` defined in *gdi32.lib*. without *gdi32.lib* you got undefined reference. *syntax is correct* - this is unrelated. syntax for compiler. symbols reference - linker task

Comment: Coding in notepad is a good way to make life as difficult as possible for yourself. There are very good reasons why IDEs and programming-oriented editors have existed for decades.

Comment: At least use `Notepad++`....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP already knows how to solve their problem (link with gdi32.lib) and just doesn't like to follow the rules imposed by the linker.  There's no actual question here.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Notepad is not what is making life difficult.  Taking libraries off the link line because (s)he feels like it, is the source of difficulty.

Comment: @zzx: How does that help? The OP doesn't feel like they should be linking against gdi32.lib when using exports from gdi32.dll. Switching editors doesn't help any. And really, aren't all the cool cats using Visual Studio Code now?

Comment: Where would I find gdi32.lib in my system?

Comment: _I'm trying to use as little outside sources as possible_: gdi32.lib as no more an _"outside souce"_ as the C compiler itself.

Answer (score 3):

> but I don't see why I should have to link the gdi library.

Because the documentation says so:

[TextOut() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-textouta)

> #### Requirements
>
> [...]
>
> Library: Gdi32.lib

Comment: Yeah...not much more to this.  gdi32.lib isn't really much of an "outside source" if you're already doing Windows code, either.

Comment: Although it occurs to me that if the OP's error is happening at "runtime", DLL linkage to the Windows libraries is probably what's happening.

Comment: @zzxyz "undefined reference to TextOut@20" is clearly a linker error.

Comment: yeah good point :)

Comment: Hmm okay. If there's no way around it I'll use the gdi library